# Google Shell doesn't see uploaded CSV file

Tags: shell, upload, debugging

I used the 'Upload' option to upload two files to Google Shell. The zip file went in without any issues and it seems like CSV file as well (there was a green checkmark next to it after the upload was completed). I also clearly see it when I run ls -la command. Yet when I try to use that file in the following code it doesn't see it and I get a message saying  "No such file or directory". Any troubleshooting tips will be greatly appreciated. I am new to Google Cloud and have no experience with debugging Power Shell.